# How to apply function on checking the specific column Null Values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a function on the dataframe by checking for NULL values on each rows of an specific column.

However i have created the function but , i am not getting how to use the function on the rows having the values.

**Input:**

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  f  e  b  a  d  a
1  c  b  a  c  b  
2  f  f  a  b  c  c
3  d  c  c  d  c  d
4  f  b  b  b  e  b
5  b  a  f  c  d  a
```

**Expected Output**

```
   A  B  C  D  E F          MATCHES   Comments
0  f  e  b  a  d a   AD, BC Unmatched
1  c  b  a  c  b      BC Unmatched    F is having blank values
2  f  f  a  b  c c   AD, BC Unmatched
3  d  c  c  d  c d      ALL MATCHED
4  f  b  b  b  e b     AD Unmatched
5  b  a  f  c  d a   AD, BC Unmatched
```

The script created is working when we don't have to check for the NaN values in df['F'] column, BUt when we check for the empty rows in df['F'] , It gives Error.

**Code i have been trying:**

```
def test(x):
    try:
       for idx in df.index:
           unmatch_list = []
           if not df.loc[idx, 'A'] == df.loc[idx, 'D']:
              unmatch_list.append('AD')
           if not df.loc[idx, 'B'] == df.loc[idx, 'C']:
              unmatch_list.append('BC')
           # etcetera...
           if len(unmatch_list):
              unmatch_string = ', '.join(unmatch_list) + ' Unmatched'
           else:
              unmatch_string = 'ALL MATCHED'
           df.loc[idx, 'MATCHES'] = unmatch_string
          
 
    except ValueError:
         print ('error')
    return df

## df = df.apply(lambda x: test(x) if(pd.notna(df['F'])) else x)

for row in df:
    if row['F'].isna() == True:
        row['Comments'] = "F is having blank values"
    else:
        df = test(df)
```

Please Suggest how can i use to function .

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
# get combis
df1 = df.copy().reset_index().melt(id_vars=['index'])
df1 = df1.merge(df1, on=['index', 'value'], how='inner')
df1 = df1[df1['variable_x'] != df1['variable_y']]
df1['combis'] = df1['variable_x'] + ':' + df1['variable_y']
df1 = df1.groupby(['index'])['combis'].apply(list)

# get empty rows
df2 = df.copy().reset_index().melt(id_vars=['index'])
df2 = df2[df2['value'].isna()]
df2 = df2.groupby(['index'])['variable'].apply(list)

# combine
df.join(df1).join(df2)

#    A  B  C  ...     F                                             combis variable
# 0  f  e  b  ...     a                                         [D:F, F:D]      NaN
# 1  c  b  a  ...  None                               [A:D, D:A, B:E, E:B]      [F]
# 2  f  f  a  ...     c                               [A:B, B:A, E:F, F:E]      NaN
# 3  d  c  c  ...     d  [A:D, A:F, D:A, D:F, F:A, F:D, B:C, B:E, C:B, ...      NaN
# 4  f  b  b  ...     b  [B:C, B:D, B:F, C:B, C:D, C:F, D:B, D:C, D:F, ...      NaN
# 5  b  a  f  ...     a                                         [B:F, F:B]      NaN
# [6 rows x 8 columns]
```

If you are only interested in the unmatched combinations you can use this:

```
import itertools
combis = [x+':'+y for x,y in itertools.permutations(df.columns, 2)]
df.join(df1).join(df2)['combis'].map(lambda lst: list(set(combis) - set(lst)))
```

Comment: Slick with the self-joins, great idea! I will say that OP seems to be looking for unmatched pairs primarily.

Comment: @Andreas - Sir Thanks for the answer, As the above function is working perfect. But while applying the function when i am trying to add a for loop to chek and apply the funtion where df['F'] is not null.

Comment: @HenryEcker, thank you! I added a solution to get only the unmatching combinations.

Comment: @NKJ if you only want to apply your function where values are not null, you can use this: `mask = ~df['F'].isna()`
`df.loc[mask] = df.loc[mask].apply(your_function)`